# How ca I put a title inside the table?

Tags: html

Here is my code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title> </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="2px">
                <tr> 
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>Address</td>
                    <td>Gender</td>
                    <td>Age</td>
                </tr>
                    <td>Pablo Job</td>
                    <td>India</td>
                    <td>Male</td>
                    <td>25</td>
        </table>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**
[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbn70.png)

How can I put the Personal Information inside the table and make it a title of the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `title` tag for HTML5 tables.
The equivalent is the `caption` tag  see : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Tables/Advanced

Semantically it is better to use it, it is 100 times more understandable for the visually impaired who use a screenreader, while using a `colspan = "4"` as here can only lead to confusion.

```css
table  {
  border-collapse : collapse;
  font-family     : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }
table caption,
table th,
table td {
  padding : .2em .8em;
  border  : 1px solid darkslategray;
  }
table caption {
  border-bottom  : none;
  font-weight    : bold;
  letter-spacing : .2em;
  font-variant   : small-caps;
  }
table thead {
  background-color : #c3e3ee;
  text-align       : left;
  }
```

```html
<table>
  <caption>Personal Information</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>Gender</th>
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>    
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Pablo Job</td>
      <td>India</td>
      <td>Male</td>
      <td>25</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Prashant Kumar</td>
      <td>India</td>
      <td>Male</td>
      <td>12</td>
    </tr>    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks sir for your explanation god bless

Answer (score 1):

You can add a row with TH element which adds a header having 4 column span.

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="4">Personal Information</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Address</td>
    <td>Gender</td>
    <td>Age</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Pablo Job</td>
    <td>India</td>
    <td>Male</td>
    <td>25</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```